# Show image which is string coming from backend(Whole image) in React UI using <img />tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, image, backend

I have been working on the upload image and getting image from the backend. My backend is returning a full image as a string(not base64 FYI). Any idea how can I change the image string to image back?
Thank you in advance.

What I tried -

1. Setting this direct as

> img src={imgString}

2. Try to use **btoa** but not able to understand why it's not working.

[image]

Comment: Try saving the image as jpg or png in a folder when uploading... You can use a file-upload library if you use express.js

Answer (score 0):

Use `<img src={url}>`. Backend receives a GET request, you need only send image either as a stream via `pipe`, or as a string